# Can I install Ubuntu 16.04 LTS along side Windows 10 in my Asus Vivobook 14 without any problem? It has an Intel i7 8th Gen processor 1TB HDD

Tags: 16.04, dual-boot, asus

Can I install Ubuntu 16.04 LTS along side Windows 10 in my Asus Vivobook S14 without any problem? It has an Intel i7 8th Gen processor 1TB HDD. I want to know if someone is using Ubuntu by dual booting on this laptop and how this is working. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi, and welcome to the site.  Unfortunately, we can make no guarantees as to whether you can instal without any problems.  Chances are, you should be able to, but there are only [three things certain](https://www.gnu.org/fun/jokes/error-haiku.html) in this world.

Answer (score 0):

It shouldn't make any difference what modern laptop you have, and your's should be fine.

From Windows make sure you have at least 50GB of unallocated space to start with for Ubuntu, then boot from a 'live' UFD. When you install Ubuntu choose the '*Something Else*' option, not the '*Install Alongside Windows*' one. There's a thorough installation procedure [here](https://tutorialsformyparents.com/how-i-dual-booted-linux-mint-alongside-windows-10-on-a-uefi-system/). Even though it's for Linux Mint, the procedure is virtually identical. Pay attention to *step 7* as that's where people often go wrong.

Regarding partitions, when it asks you if you want to create them, unlike the author in *step 4* I'd advise you to make one for `/Home`. The only other partitions needed are for your root `/`, and `/boot` - I think the latter is created automatically (can't remember). The swap partition is optional these days, and for most purposes not really necessary, but I made a 4GB one anyway just for hibernation.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer! But this model of laptop is not listed under the laptops certified by the official site of Ubuntu as compatible ones with Ubuntu. That's why I am concerned and scared if my windows partition will also get lost. Please help me regarding this.

Comment: Like I said you have nothing to worry about concerning Windows. You should have made unallocated space  on your drive and Ubuntu installs on that.

If you're that concerned about Windows then take an image of your W10  system, and store it externally. I have image back-ups for both systems.